# Foundation styling not working as expect

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I am trying to figure out why foundation is acting differently to expected behaviour. If you look at the Kitchen Sink page for foundation, the default styles for secondary buttons hover affect is different to what I get if I set foundation up in rails.

Note these images are from my rails application 
Image 1 - look at the '.tiny.secondary' button - no hover

[image]

Image 2 - look at the '.tiny.secondary' button - with hover

[image]

However on the [kitchen sink](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/kitchen_sink.html) page for foundation the color does not transition to the primary colour of the site. It transitions to a darker shade of grey.

Have I missed some setting? Really frustrating me!

I am guessing this is a bug in foundation

Comment: You're not going mad, I'm seeing this here as well for a new installation of Foundation, for various classes of `button`: secondary, alert etc.

Comment: I have dumbed the example down to jsfiddle. Seems the bug is in foundation.   http://jsfiddle.net/Sbt75/9/

Comment: They are aware of this http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/18046- Will be updated in 5.3.2 next week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted on the foundation forums and this has been fixed in version 5.3.2 and will be release next week.

http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/18046-